# How to setup "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch" in GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

Whenever the master branch is updated I want all open pull requests to show the option of **Update branch** as shown below. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

As of February 2022 this is possible without having the "**Require branches to be up to date before merging**" setting on.

The new setting is called "**Always suggest updating pull request branches**".

See the Github blog post on [More ways to keep your pull request branch up-to-date](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-03-more-ways-to-keep-your-pull-request-branch-up-to-date/#always-have-the-option-to-update), especially the section on "*Always have the option to update*".

Both can be updated in settings:

[image: Always suggest updating pull request branches]

[image: Require branches to be up to date before merging]

Comment: the require branches to be up to date before merging does not require, even if you have a status check selected :thinking:

Answer (score 8):

This configuration is part of the protected branches option.  You can create a protected branch in the repository settings and then select “Require status checks to pass before merging” and then “Require branches to be up to date before merging.”

Note that this option is the only way to get this button; if you don't want to prevent people from merging out-of-date branches, then this button won't be available.  I generally recommend not setting this option unless you have a good reason since it can make merging changes difficult if someone else merges before you, especially on busy repositories.

Comment: I agree, keeping branches up to date are really annoying. You should not do that unless necessary.  If you really need it, there are also some tools that can do that automatically for you. One I've used in past is called https://mergequeue.com/. This tool can automatically update your branch before merging.

Comment: I don't understand why CI tools have a hard time integrating merge checks as part of their system. And then you end up with mergequeue smh

Answer (score 0):

Note: with [gh 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create), you can set the option "`Always suggest updating pull request branches`" from command line with [`gh repo edit`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_edit)

```
gh repo edit --allow-update-branch
```

You can install `gh` first, with [manual installation](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) or [using `winget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/):

```
winget install GitHub.cli
```